Statistical test for whether two methods of measuring community composition produce the same distribution?
I'm measuring community composition (i.e., the distribution of abundance) of 30 taxa as captured in 3 samples at 1 site. For each of my samples, I've measured community composition using 2 different methods: DNA metabarcoding, which produced a distribution across ~1M reads, and annotation of images taken at the site, which produce a distribution across ~1K annotation points. I'd like a statistical test to tell me whether these two methods produce meaningfully different results (and so I need to use both to capture full diversity) or whether they produce the same result (and so I can just use one of them).
What is the best test to use?
Tests I've considered:

Chi-squared goodness of fit test: I think the difference in magnitude between the two methods would be an issue.
Kolmogorov-Smirnov: Requires a continuous distribution and I have a discrete distribution over nominal categories.
PERMANOVA: Seems like this would work, although power will be low with so few replicates.
Mantel Test: Seems like this would work, although power will be low with so few replicates.

Any other ideas?
UPDATE: Clarifying experiment/data structure >>
I'm seeking to measure the biomass of sessile taxa. For each sample, I've done two things: 1) taken an image of sessile organisms, created stratified random points across the image, and noted the taxa below each point; 2) scraped organisms up, extracted/amplified/sequenced their DNA, and assigned taxa to sequencing reads.
The resulting dataset looks something like this across 30 taxa (dummy data):
# Starting data (counts of annotation points for images and reads for
# metabarcoding)
df <- data.frame(
  Sample = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S1", "S2", "S3"),
  Method = c("Image", "Image", "Image", "Metabarcoding", "Metabarcoding",
             "Metabarcoding"),
  Taxa1 = c(500, 200, 1000, 100000, 200000, 150000),
  Taxa2 = c(137, 70, 500, 80000, 270000, 130000),
  Taxa3 = c(10, 90, 300, 500, 30, 160000)
)
  Sample        Method  Taxa1  Taxa2  Taxa3
1     S1         Image    500    137     10
2     S2         Image    200     70     90
3     S3         Image   1000    500    300
4     S1 Metabarcoding 100000  80000    500
5     S2 Metabarcoding 200000 270000     30
6     S3 Metabarcoding 150000 130000 160000

I then convert that into a distribution for each sample/method:
# Total annotation points or reads for each sample
s1.tot.anns <- 10000
s2.tot.anns <- 10000
s3.tot.anns <- 10000
s1.tot.reads <- 1000000
s2.tot.reads <- 1100000
s3.tot.reads <- 900000

# Convert df to distribution across taxa for each sample/method
df2 <- df
df2[1, 3:5] <- df2[1, 3:5] / s1.tot.anns
df2[2, 3:5] <- df2[2, 3:5] / s2.tot.anns
df2[3, 3:5] <- df2[3, 3:5] / s3.tot.anns
df2[4, 3:5] <- df2[4, 3:5] / s1.tot.reads
df2[5, 3:5] <- df2[5, 3:5] / s2.tot.reads
df2[6, 3:5] <- df2[6, 3:5] / s3.tot.reads

  Sample        Method     Taxa1     Taxa2         Taxa3
1     S1         Image 0.0500000 0.0137000 0.00100000000
2     S2         Image 0.0200000 0.0070000 0.00900000000
3     S3         Image 0.1000000 0.0500000 0.03000000000
4     S1 Metabarcoding 0.1000000 0.0800000 0.00050000000
5     S2 Metabarcoding 0.1818182 0.2454545 0.00002727273
6     S3 Metabarcoding 0.1666667 0.1444444 0.17777777778

Regardless of whether either method accurately estimates the distribution of biomass, I'm interested in determining whether the two methods produce meaningfully different estimates of biomass.

Mike


Have you considered a MANOVA test or ANCOVA?

What do you mean by 'annotation of images taken at the site, which produce a distribution across ~1K annotation points'? From the begning of your question I'd imaging you have a multivariate dataset (=matrix) that was built using two different techniques. If this is true, you can use a Procrustes to compare ordinations (e.g., PCoA) done with these two datasets.

Thanks for the ideas @computer_goblin @DiogoBProvete! Updated the original question to clarify exactly what I'm doing and give a data example.

From my analysis of your problem, your variables are:

Independent: Site (w/ 3 samples),Taxa (1,2, or 3), and Method(Image or Metabarcoding) which are categorical variables.
Dependent:  Some quantitative measure
So there are multiple categorical independent variables and a quantitative dependent variable
You want to analyze the effect size between the two methods for each dependent variable.

I would use either a multiple linear regression or ANCOVA test to analyze this dataset. You could use a linear regression in the form $Dependent=\beta_0+\beta_1Site+\beta_2Taxa+\beta_3Method+...(interactionTerms)+\epsilon$ and conduct an analysis on the coefficients to determine effect size, but I think this approach is a bit cumbersome since you need to categorize all your variables and think about interaction terms.
The better approach would probably be to conduct a ANCOVA test, which allows you to analyze the effect of Method on your dependent variable while controlling the other variables.
Then to analyze the if there is a significant difference, look at the effect size of your chosen statistical test. [Read more here][1]
Of course this could all be useless if I misinterpreted your problem so take this as you will.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20an%20effect%20size,based%20estimate%20of%20that%20quantity.

Thanks! I don't think it's quite right, though.

I only have 1 site, so regressing across sites isn't feasible.
I have 30 different taxa. I want to quantify whether abundance across all taxa is significantly different (I don't care about any 1 taxa in particular).
I used 2 methods to measure abundance across the 30 taxa for the same 3 samples. So, actually I have paired data, the results from the two methods aren't independent.

One other thing I've realized: my data is compositional, so I'll need to transform it (maybe a robust Aitchison) to analyze it in the real space.
